# Find count of possible power of the given element

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

You are given an array A having N integers. An element X in A is called perfect if X can be written as Y**Z for any Y >0 and Z>1

```
1<= N <= 10^5
1<= A[i] <= 10^5
```

Input:

```
2
9
6
```

Output

```
1
```

9 can be written as 3^2

```
def solve(N,A):
    count=0
    for i in A:
        for j in range(1,int(i)//2):
            for k in range(1,int(j):
                if j**k == int(i):
                    count=count+1
                    i = i + 1
    return count
```

This approach gives me correct answer for any type of input in my system unless it is in competitive coding IDE
The error message read Time Limit Exceeded
How do I overcome this problem ?

Comment: That's not exactly an error, just a sign that brute force isn't the intended way to solve the problem. Also your code is missing a parenthesis, has tons of int() calls for no clear reason, is incorrect (for example, it considers 4 not to be a power), and increments `i` instead of breaking out of the loop?

Comment: I'm intrigued by the term "perfect" as the question doesn't seem to be related to perfect numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try simple preprocessing.
First of all, based on limits you need to check approximately `n * 20` numbers (because 2 ** 20 > N), so it's `O(n)` - good, next when you processed all possible numbers you can simply compare your input with preprocessed data as follows:

```
def solve(n, a):
    MAXN = 10 ** 5 + 1
    is_perfect = [False] * MAXN

    for number in range(1, MAXN):
        for power in range(2, 20):
            if number ** power > MAXN:
                break
            is_perfect[number**power] = True

    counter = 0

    for element in a:
        if is_perfect[element]:
            counter = counter + 1

    return counter
```

Final complexity is `O(n)`